# What have i missed when writing this serial test program

Tags: c++, linux, serial-port

I am having serious trouble with rs232 communications in linux so i wrote this test program to make sure it was not other parts of my program interfering with the serial communications.

The program however does not work so as i feared it is the serial port code that is the problem.

I have a laptop with centos running the program and that is connected to a computer with windows xp running hyperterminal. the code executes ok according to the error checking but nothing is showing up in huperterminal.

The serial pore setup I am trying to achive is 115200 baud rate, 8 databits, 1 stopbit and mark parity.

This is the program:

```
#include <termios.h>
#include <sys/ioctl.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <ncurses.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <unistd.h> 

int main()
{
int port, serial, i;
unsigned long nobw;
char buf[10];
struct termios options;

port = open("/dev/ttyS0", O_RDWR | O_NOCTTY | O_NDELAY);

if (port == -1)
    perror("open_port: Unable to open /dev/ttyS0 - ");  
else
    printf("port open \n");

tcgetattr(port, &options); // get current settings

cfsetispeed(&options, 115200); // set baud rate
cfsetospeed(&options, 115200); // set baud rate

options.c_cflag &= ~CSIZE; // Mask the character size bits 
options.c_cflag |= CS8; // 8 bit data           
options.c_cflag &= ~PARENB; // set parity to no 
options.c_cflag &= ~PARODD; // set parity to no 
options.c_cflag |= CSTOPB;//set mark parity by using 2 stop bits 

options.c_cflag |= (CLOCAL | CREAD);

options.c_oflag &= ~OPOST;

options.c_lflag &= 0;
options.c_iflag &= 0; //disable software flow controll
options.c_oflag &= 0;

tcsetattr(port, TCSANOW, &options);// save the settings

ioctl(port, TIOCMGET, &serial);
serial |= TIOCM_DTR; // set DTR to high
ioctl(port, TIOCMSET, &serial);

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    buf[i] = i;
}

for(i = 0; i < 10; i++)
{
    errno = 0;
    nobw = write(port, buf, 1);
    if(nobw == -1) 
        perror("WriteComm:");
    else 
        printf("sent character %d \n", i);
}
return 0;
}
```

This is all done from tutorials on the interned i have little idea what im doing, can you see where i have gone wrong ?

also if anyone knows how to do space parity that would also be appreciated.

Comment: I don't remember much about RS232 and I've never programmed it on linux, but could you try connecting the rx and tx pins (#2 and 3 AFAIR) on the port to see if you're getting all the output echoed back as input?

Comment: @Alex how would I connect the pins ? I will be in big trouble if I damage the laptop. If hypothetically it was echoed back as input what would your solution be ? maybe I could implement that instead of connecting the pins to see if it was the trouble ?

Comment: with something metallic. AFAIR, the port on the computer has a male 9-pin connector, so the safest and easiest may be to short-circuit rx and tx not on it, but on the cable that has female connectors on both sides and attached to the computer with one end. You'd just need to insert a reshaped paper clip into the holes for rx and tx on the free end. You can't damage anything with that, unless you short-circuit the wrong pins. If there's echo, I'd start checking if the port is configured identically on both devices. I'd also lower the rate to 9600 and turn off all the DTR stuff.

Comment: google up pinout for rs232 9-pin.

Comment: @Alex I am communicating with a device that hast to have these settings :( that's what's causing me all the trouble. secondly im not sure how to configure the port, that was kind on my question lol everything iv got so far is off the net and i have no way of telling whats good and whats not.

Comment: Well, first of all - what cable are you using? Is it just full cable or limited 3 or 5 wires (gnd/rx/tx, gnd/rx/tx/cts/rts)? Null modem or straight one? Have you tried to send and receive at least something with other software? What does `echo '1' > /dev/ttyS0`?

Comment: I don't have a linux box with a serial port nor your device to try and see what happens. I can only tell you what steps I'd take to ensure that there's some communication, that at least the right port is selected and it functions. Btw, if you have another computer with a serial port, you may first check the communication with it. And only after it works, start playing with the device. Another idea... You could just try a number of different options (from those you're unsure about, if any) and see if any works.

Comment: @Andrejs i have tested the cable( see answer below), cts and rts should be disabled so that should not matter, no idea what "Null modem or straight one?" means and echo '1' > /dev/ttyS0 does nothing, it runs without any message or anything, does that mean something to you ?

Comment: google 'null modem' - short answer, it's a cable that allows direct serial connection between two serial ports (tx on one machine to rx on the other and vice versa). - note that 9 pin serial ports have pins 2 & 3 with reversed functions from a 25 pin serial port (tx/rx)

Comment: I would recommend that while testing, inside your loop to set `buf` you do the following `buf[i] = i + 0x30;` That way the data you send is human readable. Also change your write line to `nobw = write(port, buf[i], 1);`

Comment: Finally, through the command line, you can run `stty` to set your serial port parameters.  Frequently this is faster than changing your program each time you want to try something

Comment: look to the right (Related column) and see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1558705/serial-device-reading-8n1-works-but-writing-a-single-byte-fails

Answer (score 0):

Maybe worth checking if the setup works without your code? :)
If you connect using minicom on the linux side and hyperterminal on the windows side, can you pass data back and forth?

Comment: How you have tested? Are you sure that the cable is not a problem?

Comment: we have a java program that uses the serial port and i ran that and its out put showed up in hyper terminal. the cable is not the problem.

Comment: Hmm but man tcsetattr only mentions even and odd parity, not mark parity :( It may not be supported at that level. Your code just sets the parity to 'no parity'.

Comment: Well the options look fine (to my limited knowledge). Another test you can make: if you just set 8N1 - or even/odd parity since we know that is supported - can you see your output on the other machine?

Comment: Also, all examples of using parity i can google seem to use 7 data bits not 8.

Comment: even when i change the parity nothing is happening. i know the cable and ports work so there must be some command or setting that i have missed.